# JavaScript bind inside

Tags: javascript

If you look at the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2hjffu60/2/) you can see the output that when I try to call bind to bind to `this` (in the fiddle this is the window) that the console writes undefined to the screen.

This is a pared down example from my project, but the problem is the same.  Why is binding setPagingData not writing `stuff from outside pager` not being written to the console?

```
var Pager = (function(){
            function Pager(){


            }

            Pager.prototype.setPagingData = function(){


                console.log(this.stuff);
            };
            return Pager;
})();
var stuff = 'stuff from outside pager';
var pager = new Pager();
console.log(pager);
pager.setPagingData.bind(this);
pager.setPagingData();
```

Comment: In your fiddle, the code is placed inside the `load` event handler, i.e. `stuff` is not becoming a global variable. Change `onLoad` to `no wrap <head>`.

Comment: Note that `bind()` returns a new function; it does not modify the original function.  You don't store this function anywhere, so that line basically does nothing at all.

Comment: @FelixKling can you explain more about that behavior, e.g. why doing that works?

Comment: If you change the setting then the code is placed in the global scope, and `stuff` will be global. However you still have to assign and use the return value of `.bind()`.

Comment: @FelixKling I meant what the heck is actually going on changing that.  FYI, I had referred to you as King Felix, but you're KLing Felix :)

Comment: Oh, uhm, not 100% what you mean. You can have a look at the page source of the iframe and see the difference. With `onLoad`, the generated code will be something like `window.onload = function() { /* your code here */};` and without it it will just be `/*your code here*/`. Is that what you mean? Also: For some reason many people on SO misread my last name :)

Comment: Yes, that's it, and it's the kerning.